# How do you pronounce '(Mission) Chang'e (嫦娥) 5` in French, and why?

Tags: emprunts

How would you pronounce the Chinese "(Mission) **Chang'e** (嫦娥) 5" in French, especially the last part ('e), and why?

Comment: The original Chinese name contained a syllable transliterated as “e.” This isn’t specific to French language.

Comment: /tʃaŋ(g).œ/, /tʃaŋ(g).ø/, /tʃaŋ(g).wœ/ and /tʃaŋ(g).wø/ all seem like possible francisations of the native pronunciations I'm hearing on different online sources

Comment: @Eauquidort N'hesite pas à verser ça en réponse. Je répondais à l'oreille mais je ne trouve pas ma réponse particulièrement convaincante et je n'ai pas tenté de vérifier ce qui se dit comme tu l'as fait.

Comment: En passant la question a été modifiée et ne mérite pas -1 il me semble.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Chinese language is not on topic but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e) says "Chinese: 嫦娥; pinyin: *Cháng'é*"; the two elements it's seemingly made of sound like this individually ([1](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zh-ch%C3%A1ng.ogg), [2](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zh-%C3%A9.ogg)); the IPA is   [ʈʂʰǎŋ.ɤ̌]. I would most likely pronounce "tchang-euh cinq(5)" in French by trying to mimic what I perceive from that, trying to respect the original Chinese pronunciation as much as I can (but it's challenging). I would add, for more certainty, "(la) sonde spatiale (de retour d'échantillons lunaires) de l'agence spatiale chinoise (CNSA), du nom de la déesse de la Lune dans la mythologie chinoise" (based on [Wikipedia's description and referencing in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_5)). Also I would want to avoid any confusion with the word "change" in English.

> La mission **"Tchang-euh"(Chang'e) cinq**, la sonde spatiale (de retour d'échantillons
> lunaires) de l'agence spatiale chinoise (CNSA), du nom de la déesse de
> la Lune dans leur mythologie.